# Find MAX of COUNT in SQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have SQL table information of runs like time, distance, pace ... I would like to have information of the best maximum runned distance by the month by user. I need to COUNT runned distance by every month and find the best one (MAX).

My table looks like this:

```
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| ID | USERID | MONTH  | DISTANCE |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 1  |    1   | 201707 |   6.69   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 2  |    2   | 201707 |   6.03   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 3  |    2   | 201707 |   6.02   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 4  |    1   | 201706 |   7.25   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 5  |    1   | 201706 |   7.13   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 6  |    2   | 201705 |   7.03   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 7  |    3   | 201705 |   6.31   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 8  |    1   | 201705 |   5.28   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 9  |    1   | 201704 |   4.44   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 10 |    2   | 201704 |   5.94   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
```

I try this but I have no output:

```
$select3run = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT month, MAX(mycount) FROM (SELECT month, SUM(distance) AS mycount FROM runbeh GROUP BY month, distance) a GROUP BY month");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($select3run)) {
$max=$data['mycount'];
}

echo $max;
```

Have no more idea how to find value I'm looking for. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Is this a MySQL question or a PHP question? If it is about MySQL then please post only the query, without the PHP that handles it. If you also have problems with the PHP that handles the query then create another question for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a proper alias for the column name eg: `my_max`

```
    $select3run = mysqli_query($conn, "
        SELECT month, MAX(mycount)  as my_max
        FROM (SELECT month, SUM(distance) AS mycount 
        FROM runbeh GROUP BY month, distance) a 
        GROUP BY month");
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($select3run)) {
      $max=$data['my_max'];
    }

    echo $max;
```

Comment: Many thanks, you hepl me a lot. I just remove GROUP BY distance in the middle and replace GROUP BY month by GROUP BY mycount in the end and use LIMIT 1 ... and it's work :)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29009f/8

SQL:

```
SELECT r.userid, r.month, max(r.sumdistance) 
FROM
(
  SELECT userid, month, sum(distance) as sumdistance 
  FROM runners 
  GROUP BY month, userid
) as r 
GROUP BY r.userid
```

Comment: This work great, but not like I want to. I want to know the best one of userid from all. If userid runs first month 7.00km + 6.50km + 6.65km + 5.98km and second month runs 6.50km + 6.66km + 7.03km + 7.24km  I want to dislay the best of. For example USERID=1 MONTH=201705 RUNNED=27.43km == Best month (the most KM runned per month) for userid1

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I updated my answer on your comment

Comment: I'm sorry. My English is not very good, lots of words I try to find on dictionary :) I'm thanksful that you helping me.

Comment: OK, this looks like it will be too complicate to me. I change the string names - month = inttyzden, distance = vzdialenost and use it like this: $select2run = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT r.userid, r.inttyzden, max(r.sumdistance) FROM (SELECT userid, inttyzden, sum(vzdialenost) as sumdistance FROM runbeh GROUP BY inttyzden, userid) as r GROUP BY r.userid");
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($select2run); 
RESULT: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Many thanks to Raimondas Kazlauskas and scaisEdge whos show me the way and help me.

Working code for show most distance runned per month by users:

```
$select3run = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT month, MAX(mycount)  as my_max 
FROM
(SELECT month, SUM(distance) AS mycount FROM runners GROUP BY month) a GROUP 
BY mycount DESC LIMIT 1");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($select3run)) {
$max=$data['my_max'];
echo $max; }
```

Where $max is the biggest SUM of distance which was runned by one month by user.

Answer (score -1):

You should Try this one :-

Best run by every month of every user :-

select max(distance) AS MaxDistance,userid from runbeh group by month,userid

Note :- Never put any aggregate function in Group BY clause